# The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.ads.AdView

Tags: java, android

I can't get my APP run... that's the problem in `activitymain_xml`. Could someone help me ?
That's the `layout activity`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context="com.denisprojects.shoppinglist.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >



   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/add" />
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adsView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/button2"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5426545253667840/7625762411"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I already see the others quests, but i still couldn't get my APP run. Sorry for my english, hope you will understand .

Comment: Make sure you have added library file in your project's build path.

Comment: I add it ... And i add the lines in AndroidManifest .. I really can't understand where is the problem ... maybe someone know

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also declare the AdActivity in your AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Comment: Yes .. i imported lib admodsdk 6.4 and google play and added its to build path .... still get the error.

Comment: The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.ads.AdView

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might have forget to add the google ads library file in your project's build path.

[image]